# Admissible (unitary) spherical representation $sl(2,Q_p)$. Does dimension fixed point vector increase proportional index

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, trees, hecke-algebras, admissible-representation

I am using terminology of Cartier's Harmonic analysis on trees. Take $\pi$ be  one of the irreducible principal or complementary (unitary) spehrical series of $Sl(2, Q_p)$. Let $K$ be the maximal compact subgroup and $K_0$ on of the modular subgroups of finite index. Denote by $V$ the space on which $\pi$ acts. Let $V^K, V^{K_0}$ be the fixed vectors with respect to  $K, K_0$, Being spherical and irreducible gives dim  $V^K=1$, but is it true that dim $V^{K_0}$=$[K:K_0]$? I saw in a PhD thesis (www.uni-math.gwdg.de/preprint/mg.2000.10.ps.gz) the proof for less or  equal, but I wonder if there is equality, or if there is a difference between principal and suplementary series of irreducible representations?

Comment: or perhaps is this an old form principle (Attkins Lehner type) so that the dimension associated to $\Gamma_0(p^n)$ is only $n+1$?

Comment: What is a modular subgroup? Also, $SL(2,\mathbb Q_p)$ has two conjugacy classes of maximal compact subgroups.